# how do i generate series of numbers?

Tags: php, random, numbers, series

i need help to generate series of number and it should be generate series of number when
`form is submitted` i have code but it not working properly?

**For Example I Want Like This**

```
00500
00501
00502
00503  and so on...
```

**Here My Code**

```
$random = rand(500,999);
$new_val = $random+1;
for($i=1;$i<=$new_val;$i++)
{
if( strlen($i)==1 )
{
$say='0000'.$i;
}
elseif( strlen($i)==2 )
{
$say='000'.$i;
}
elseif( strlen($i)==3 )
{
$say='00'.$i;
}
elseif( strlen($i)==4 )
{
$say='0'.$i;
}
elseif( strlen($i)==5 )
{
$say=$i;
}
}

<form method="post">
<input class="input_field" readonly="readonly" type="text" 
name="sno" id="sno" value="<?=$say?>"  >
<input type="submit" name="test" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `sprintf` to format it:

```
<?php

$start = rand(500, 999);

for ($i = 1; $i <= $start; $i++) {
    $num = sprintf("%05d", $i);
    echo $num;
}

?>
```

Comment: rand(500, 999) should not be in the for loop, as it is evaluated at each loop.

Comment: @F.C.: Thanks, I completely missed that.

Answer (score 0):

As Blender says, use [sprintf](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to format your numbers

```
$start = rand(500, 999);
for ($i = $start; $i <= 999; $i++) {
    $num = sprintf("%1$05d", $i);
    echo $num . '<br>';
}
```

Note that the [form](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3) must contain an "action" attribute